# How to refresh relational property of a LINQ class?

Tags: linq, northwind

I have two instances of a program that manipulate same Northwind database.
When I add some records to the database from one of the instances (for example adding some orders to Orders table with a customer foreign key `John`), I can query these new records from the other instance of the program properly. The problem begins when I want to access these new records using `John.Orders`. In this situation, the second instance of the program does not see newly added records. What should I do?

Comment: did you mean relational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is probably related to the time you keep the LINQ to SQL `DataContext` class alive. It should typically be destroyed after each unit of work you do with it (since it follows the 'unit of work' design pattern), which typically means after each use case / business transaction.

You are probably keeping the `DataContext` class alive during the entire lifetime of the application. The `DataContext` class is not suited for this, because it will cache all objects it had once retrieved meaning that your data will get stale.

Create a new `DataContext` class for every operation or every time the user opens a new form / screen.

Comment: In my real world code, for some reasons I need to keep my database open. So this solution won't work for me.